# How to sort an array of hashes into hashes with multiple values for a key?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am working on Ruby on Rails project using rails4.

Scenario:

I have an array of hashes. An array contains hashes where keys are the same.

```
 a = [{132=>[1000.0]}, {132=>[4000.0]}, {175=>[1000.0]}, {175=>[1000.0]}, {133=>[1200.0]}]
 h = a.each {|key,value| key.each {|k| value}}
#{132=>[1000.0]}
#{132=>[4000.0]}
#{175=>[1000.0]}
#{175=>[1000.0]}
#{133=>[1200.0]}
```

Problem:

How to get rid off duplicate keys but with values added to unique keys like this:

```
 {132=>[1000,4000]}
 {175=>[1000,1000]}
 {133=>[1200]}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would do it:

```
a.inject({}) {|sum, hash| sum.merge(hash) {|_, old, new| old + new }}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
p a.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) { |e, h| e.each { |k, v| h[k] += v } }

# => {132=>[1000.0, 4000.0], 175=>[1000.0, 1000.0], 133=>[1200.0]}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will think it through.

Comment: Do you mean that you like the possibility to avoid a condition by set a default hash value?=). Or you are hinting that it could be done another way?

Comment: I didn't express myself well, but what I meant is that I liked `Hash.new([])` and `h[k] += v` better than what I thought to be the main alternative: `Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}` and `h[k] << v.first`. On reflection, however, the former may be less efficient, as a new array is created when each element is added.  Hmmm. Would you mind doing an edit, so I can roll back my +1?. Actually, `(h[k] ||= []) <<... ` probably would be quite a bit faster yet.  (Nix the edit request. :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  k, v = g.to_a.flatten
  (h[k] ||= []) << v
end
  #=> {132=>[1000.0, 4000.0], 175=>[1000.0, 1000.0], 133=>[1200.0]}
```

or

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |g,h|
  k, v = g.to_a.flatten
  h[k] << v
end
  #=> {132=>[1000.0, 4000.0], 175=>[1000.0, 1000.0], 133=>[1200.0]}
```

Comment: Nice approach as usual.